# Sorting issue with pandas dataframe (or python list/tuple)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame which looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
 (638009197035522, 655784141500417), # 0
 (693075572527105, 693075572527105), # 1
 (655784141500417, 693668642918400), # 2
 (693075572527105, 694397537353729), # 3
 (694397537353729, 695737600794624), # 4
 (695737600794624, 700168400654337), # 5
 (693075572527105, 929811762360322), # 6
 (929811762360322, 931830115979265), # 7
 (931830115979265, 951912745500672), # 8
 (951912745500672, 965073687117824)] # 9

pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['reference', 'uid'])
```

It is sorted by the second column (uid). What I would like to achieve, however, is to sort (or rebuild) dataframe in a way that it will look like as follows:

```
[(638009197035522, 655784141500417), # 0->0
 (655784141500417, 693668642918400), # 2->1
 (693075572527105, 693075572527105), # 1->2
 (693075572527105, 694397537353729), # 3->3
 (694397537353729, 695737600794624), # 4->4
 (693075572527105, 929811762360322), # 6->5
 (695737600794624, 700168400654337), # 5->6
 (929811762360322, 931830115979265), # 7->7
 (931830115979265, 951912745500672), # 8->8
 (951912745500672, 965073687117824)] # 9->9
```

That is, the value in the second column (uid) determines which specific row comes next in dataframe/list, but not always as you can see. In its original shape, it is sorted by the uid column, which is okay until there is a row with a reference key to this uid.

The solution does not have to be a pandas/dataframe one, pure python solution also will work.

**EDIT**

As Ted pointed out I made a mistake in the desired result data and I guess I should also have given more perspective into the data and my goals. The data is imitation of a sample of tweet data, with only referenced tweet ids along with ids of the original tweets, sorted by creation time (ascending).

Now, in the sample, if reference and id is the same, it means it is the first node in conversation. If it is not, then it is a reply to another tweet.

I want to keep the order, in case there is an exceptions:

Exception 1: A reply

Exception 2: A reply to another reply, here it goes, as long as sub-conversations

```
[(522, 417), # 0->0 # 417, head
 (417, 400), # 2->1 # reply to 417 (chronologically after 105)
 (105, 105), # 1->2 # 105, new entry, so keep the order for now
 (105, 729), # 3->3 # 729, reply to 105
 (729, 624), # 4->4 # 624, reply to 729 (a reply to 105)
 (624, 337), # 5->5 # 337, reply to 624 (a reply to 729)
 (105, 322), # 6->6 # 322, another reply to 105 
 (322, 265), # 7->7 # so it goes...
 (265, 672), # 8->8
 (672, 824)] # 9->9
```

The data indicates that there are two different conversation here. So, I'd like to keep the data chronically but break it in cases where the conversations (reply) and sub-conversations (reply to reply, ...) take place.

Also, as Quang Hoang pointed out, I looked into networkx/graph stuff. Definitely looks related. Also linked lists appear to be a solution, but could not find a definite solution.

Comment: Looks like a network problem. Checkout `networkx` package.

Comment: No, it is not. AFAIK in network analysis the order is not important at all. But in my case, that is the exact problem.

Comment: In a **directed** network/graph, the order **is** important.

Comment: you will have to iterate it - to get next row and put in new dataframe, and remove from old dataframe. Maybe dictionary could be useful for this - first column as key, second column as value - but it may need OrderedDictionary to keep order.

Comment: i tried to use dictionary but in `reference` you have the same number few times - so it can't be as key in dictionary.

Comment: I'll give a proper answer if you could explain the logic behind swapping rows # 4->5->6 to #4->6->5?

Comment: @Ted You are right, I made a mistake along these lines. Edited the question and added more perspective.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['reference', 'uid'])
df.sort_values(by="reference", inplace=True)
df

    reference       uid
0   638009197035522 655784141500417
2   655784141500417 693668642918400
1   693075572527105 693075572527105
3   693075572527105 694397537353729
6   693075572527105 929811762360322
4   694397537353729 695737600794624
5   695737600794624 700168400654337
7   929811762360322 931830115979265
8   931830115979265 951912745500672
9   951912745500672 965073687117824
```

Then a further sort along the lines of

```
df['uid'].isin(df['reference'])
```